# Connecting to SQL Server 2008 on windows server 2008

Tags: sql-server, remote

Hell all

I am new to windows server 2008 and we are trying to transfer our website from hosting to virtual server.

I installed SQL Server 2008 Express edition and I did the things like opening port and allowing them through the firewall but I can't log into to the remote server from my local machine.

I am not quite sure which IP address to use to connect to SQL Server from local machine whether is it servers IP address or will SQL give us a different IP address.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: The Express editions don't support remote connections by default - you need to [enable remote connections on SQL Server 2008 Express](http://www.linglom.com/2009/03/28/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)

Answer (score 2):

You will be using the servername (DNS) or the IP address of the server.  But if you have a named instance (as opposed to the default instance), your servername will be followed by `\instanceName`.

So, in other words unless you changed any SQL Server Express install defaults, you should connect to the server like this:

```
yourServerName\sqlexpress
```

SQL Server Express has a default named instance name of `SQLEXPRESS`.  Also, since SQL Server Express is a named instance, you'll need to ensure that your SQL Server Browser service is running.

Another one.  If you are trying to connect to SQL Server from a separate machine, you'll need to ensure that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled for SQL Server.

The above two points can be verified and configured in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Also if you are connecting to a named instance remotely you will need to open up a firewall port for 1434 and make sure that the SQLBrowser service is running so it can translate the named instance into a port and then redirect your client connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Sql Management Studio to connect to your database server, all you need to do is to enable Sql Server Browser service on the Windows Server 2008. You will find that in Sql Server Configuration Manager -> Sql Server Services -> Sql Server Browser.

If it's a development machine or a VM you could disable windows firewall.

Also follow the steps from here: 
http://www.linglom.com/2007/08/31/enable-remote-connection-to-sql-server-2005-express/